# Running commands from a Java Program

Tags: java, terminal

This code should execute a command line, but it only works for certain commands. For instance, it works for opening up and running a jar file, but it cannot seem to execute the command:

```
echo 'Hello World' > HelloWorld.txt
```

which should create a txt file called HelloWorld. Can someone help me figure the problem out?

```
public static void command(String command) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? Are you aware of the difference between "real" commands and "shell builtins"?  Also, you should read up on `ProcessBuilder` as it is the modern way to launch subprocesses in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you have `>` in your command and you input as a string to `exec` function. I don't exactly know why exec command cannot execute such statement, but if you have pipe `|`, or redirection `>` , etc it can't handle it when command is given as an string input. what you have to do is run it as a separate script, ie as follows

```
public static void command(String command) {
    try {
        String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c" , command };  // you have to input an string array your command will be executed in a new shell.
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

new shell process will get created by /bin/sh and whole command (including redirect) get executed there before returning.